# multiple definition error from dl-addr.c with addition of printf, in glibc compilation

Tags: compilation, linker, glibc

In `glibc-2.13/nptl/sigaction.c`, i just put a simple `printf("test\n");` and my glibc compilation fails. Just adding a `printf` gives me multiple definitions of `_itoa` from `dl-addr.c` and i have no idea why.

Can any body please tell me why is this happening and possible solution. The error:

```
test/glibc-build/libc_pic.a(_itoa.os): In function `_itoa':
test/glibc-2.13/stdio-common/_itoa.c:215: multiple definition of 
`_itoa'
test/glibc-build/elf/dl-allobjs.os:test/glibc-2.13/elf/dl-minimal.c:300: first defined here
test/glibc-build/libc_pic.a(dl-addr.os): In function `_dl_addr_inside_object':
test/SOURCE/glibc-2.13/elf/dl-addr.c:156: multiple definition of   
`_dl_addr_inside_object'
test/glibc-build/elf/dl-allobjs.os:glibc-2.13/elf/dl-open.c:658: first defined here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just adding a printf gives me multiple definitions of _itoa

Don't do *that*.

Glibc is quite complicated, and you need to know what you are doing when you modify it.

What's happening is that the link for `elf/ld.so` fails (you didn't say what target is failing, but I am pretty sure it's the `ld.so`; in the future please show the *entire* error message, not just parts of it).

The `ld.so` is the *dynamic linker*, that will eventually bind your program to `printf` in `libc.so.6`. For obvious reason, `ld.so` itself can't dynamically link to `printf` -- it must execute before `libc.so.6` has even been `mmap`ed. As such, it links in minimal parts of `libc.a`, just enough for it to get running. The `printf` is not part of that minimal runtime, so you can't "just add a call to it".